# The image in django doesn't work

Tags: python, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

I use the carousel in bootstrap

I made the two version.

One is the html static file.

The other is in Django framework,

But I can't use django to do the following result .

The following is html static file.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html >
 <head lang="zh-Hant-TW">
 <title></title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width ,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="panel panel-warning">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Most Popular Products</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="bestSellers" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <li data-target="#bestSellers" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                                <li data-target="#bestSellers" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                                <li data-target="#bestSellers" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                                <li data-target="#bestSellers" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                            </ol>

                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <img src="images/spring.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">Product 1</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="images/summer.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">Product 2</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="images/autumn.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">Product 3</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item">
                                    <img src="images/winter.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                                    <div class="carousel-caption">Product 4</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#bestSellers" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#bestSellers" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>













        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="panel panel-warning">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Weather data</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                      </ol>
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                          <img src="images/spring.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="images/summer.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="images/autumn.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 3</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="images/winter.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 4</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

-----------------------Django code-------------------------------------

```
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                <div class="panel panel-warning">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Weather data</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                      </ol>
                      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                          <img src="images/spring.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="images/summer.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="images/autumn.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 3</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                          <img src="images/winter.jpg" alt="First slide" class="img-responsive">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">data 4</div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            </a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

The following is the djano piece code, the differ is in image format

Others code are the same

But the result in django is the four vertical pictures fulled of the page.

how do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/) of using static files.

In short you need to use `src="{% static url '(path)/(name).(format)" %}"`

At the top of your template you'll also need `{% load staticfiles %}` and to have your static paths set properly of course + url configuration.

Comment: Yes i actually added in my local file,sry i forgot added in my question haha.btw the problem still exist